# Access of a protected member functions through a pointer is not allowed

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism, protected

So, I want to create a class `B` that inherits from another class `A`, and `A` has a `std::vector<A> Avecs` as a protected member function.
What I want to do is access `A`'s member function through `Avecs`but it says that it is protected within this context, which is weird, because I can already use `Avecs` in `B`

Here's what I want to do:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::vector<int> data); // to initialize all Aobjs - constructor1
    A(int data);              // to initialize the internals of each Aobjs - constructor2

protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> Aobjs;
    int get() { return 1; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(std::vector<int> data) : A(data) {} // calls A's constructor2
    void fun()                            // a function which has what I want to do
    {
        Aobjs[0]->get(); // this is the line that throws the error: ' is protected within this context'
    }
};
```

Why can't I do this, I think it's fair because B already inherited Aobjs which is a protected member, so we're just calling a protected member through another protected member.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `protected` inheritance only allows `B` to access members of its base, not other arbitrary objects of type `A`

Comment: I'm trying public inheritance.